# How to define total-executor-cores in spark config files?

Tags: apache-spark

The total-executor-cores is parameter for spark command line, such as spark-shell, spark-submit. I hope config such parameter in spark-defaults.conf or spark-env.sh. I did't find alternative of this parameter in [Spark documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html). please help me.

Update:
spark.cores.max have similar function with total-executor-cores

Comment: Since you know what property you need to set in the config file, what is your question?

Comment: I updated my question, so this question included my answer.

Comment: In that situation, what you should do is answer your own question and accept that answer, showing to other users that it is correct. It sounds weird, but it may actually help others who encounter the same problem as you find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spark.cores.max have similar function with total-executor-cores